# Add ngModel directive to dynamic element in Javascript

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

Is there a way to use javascript to apply the ng-model directive to a created element? In the code below, I want the new select element to be bound using ng-model to a scoped variable inside the controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('dynamicHtml', function ($q, $http, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        scope: '=',
        compile: function(element, attr) {
              return function(scope, element, attr) {

              var select = document.createElement('select');
              // Here I want to use javascript to apply ng-model='controllerVar' 
              // to the new select element
              element.append(select);
             }
    }
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoops - my apologies...I forgot to compile the thing...carry on.